# Kitten fast breathing while sleeping

Tags: cats, health

My 3 month old kitten is breathing quite fast while sleeping after a round of running around and playing. Currently the house is about 28.5 degrees Celsius, so its quite hot.

She also breathes with her mouth open but only after she runs for 15 mins straight.

She eats regularly and sleeps well, drinks water normally and is very very active.

Should I be concerned? What do you guys think, is it normal given the warm weather and physical activity?

Here is an example: https://streamable.com/cm1g2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please take your cat to the vet right now.**

Your cat might have heart problems or an infection so you ned to get help for your kitten as fast as possible.

If a cats breathing does not slow down after about five minutes when resting your cat needs help fast.

The heat in the house is a factor in this but probably not the only cause for your cat breathing this fast.

It is not unusual for cats to have periods of fast breathing during sleep but this is often after your cat have had vivid dreams so it will slow down quite fast when the dreams are over.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will take her to the vet asap. The breathing slows down eventually, and during night time it seems quite regular (around 40 breaths / minute)

Comment: @RusPaul many cats have heart murmurs https://vcahospitals.com/know-your-pet/heart-murmurs-in-cats and sometimes it can be a sign of heart problems.rapid breath can be a sign of problems so it is best to have a vet examine your cat,my cat have murmurs and this is why i react like i do when i answered your question as unexplained rapid breathing might be a sign of problems.

Comment: Thanks! I will definetly ask my vet about it! Best wishes for your cat as well!